# How to send UINavigationBar Items to Back of the NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar with some items like below screenshot. I need to send those items to back of the navigation bar for making them visible behind the overlay but there should not be user Interaction like second image below after clicking a button:

[image: Before overlay]

[image: After Overlay]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fake it.

Set alpha to .3, then turn set UserInteractionEnabled = NO on each of those items.

Disclaimer: never done this before, and can't test it, but this would be my first approach.

Comment: Thank you Daryl, It's Working now.But i need to enable UserInteraction on clicking the navigation bar which is currently disabled. How can i achieve it?

Comment: Don't change UserInteraction on the Bar, change it on the individual elements.

Comment: Exactly.. Thank you very much for your helping and let me learn learn some more knowledge with the help of seniors like you. Thank you once again..

Answer (score 2):

used it:
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setAlpha:0.5];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];